# Change my own suggested edit

Tags: support, editing, review

Is there any way to change/ withdraw a suggested edit I made, while it's in the review process?

I started to edit a [post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/34906/668), but in the same time another user with edit privileges changed it even better, not only correcting the spelling, but also adding some more informations. So when I finally submitted my edit, it appeared like I have take down some of the good infos added.

As the edit was done in the review process, before clicking I'm done, I saw that the post was already modified, but I could't find any way to revert/reject it.

My question is if there exists some option to solve myself this kind of problem or I should just wait for my post to be rejected by the community.

Comment: +1 from me for this question -- and additionally asking what can be done from the other side: After I saved my edit (yeoo, guilty ;) I saw Adinia's edit in the review queue. I wanted to give her credit for it without losing/overwriting mine (as it took considerable time to make it, for both edits), but saw no way to do it. If this side of the medal could be considered in the answer, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you edit again it will overwrite your first suggestion, as long as that suggestion has not already been approved or rejected.

As for Izzy's comment: Hit the "Improve" button.  This will allow you to fix up the post to contain all the fixes (use "view source" in the edit history if needed) and there is a checkbox for whether the suggested edit was helpful in the improvement effort or not.